# Trim wav file method using Javazoom sometimes works

Tags: java, android, audio, wav

I'm working on a method to trim a wav file down to a selection made by the user.  The basic idea is to use Javazoom's `WaveFile` class to write a wav file that contains only that sound data in the selection made by the user.  The problem is, the code I have written works perfectly about half the time and the other half of the time it produces static.  It seems to work and not work under the same exact same circumstances.  The wav file is loaded at another time by `MediaPlayer` and as an input stream in other methods.  Is this the likely source of the issue?  I've tried to take care to close streams and release `MediaPlayer`, but continue to have the same issue.

```
public void TrimToSelection(double startTime, double endTime){ // Time in seconds
    InputStream wavStream = null; // InputStream to stream the wav to trim
    File trimmedSample = null;  // File to contain the trimmed down sample
    File sampleFile = new File(samplePath); // File pointer to the current wav sample

    // If the sample file exists, try to trim it
    if (sampleFile.isFile()){
        trimmedSample = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC), "trimmedSample.wav");
        if (trimmedSample.isFile()) trimmedSample.delete(); // Delete if already exists

        // Trim the sample down and write it to file
        try {
            wavStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(sampleFile));
            // Javazoom class WaveFile is used to write the wav
            WaveFile waveFile = new WaveFile();
            waveFile.OpenForWrite(trimmedSample.getAbsolutePath(), (int)audioFormat.getSampleRate(), (short)audioFormat.getSampleSizeInBits(), (short)audioFormat.getChannels());
            // The number of bytes of wav data to trim off the beginning
            long startOffset = (long)(startTime * audioFormat.getSampleSizeInBits() * audioFormat.getSampleRate() / 4);
            // The number of bytes to copy
            long length = (long)(endTime * audioFormat.getSampleSizeInBits() * audioFormat.getSampleRate() / 4) - startOffset;
            wavStream.skip(44); // Skip the header
            wavStream.skip(startOffset);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 16];
            int bufferLength;
            for (long i = startOffset; i < length + startOffset; i += buffer.length){
                bufferLength = wavStream.read(buffer);
                short[] shorts = new short[buffer.length / 2];
                ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer().get(shorts);
                waveFile.WriteData(shorts, shorts.length);
            }
            waveFile.Close(); // Complete writing the wave file
            wavStream.close(); // Close the input stream
        } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        finally {
            try {if (wavStream != null) wavStream.close();} catch (IOException e){}
        }
    }
    // Delete the original wav sample
    sampleFile.delete();
    // Copy the trimmed wav over to replace the sample
    trimmedSample.renameTo(sampleFile);
}
```

**Update:**  I changed `long startOffset = (long)(startTime * audioFormat.getSampleSizeInBits() * audioFormat.getSampleRate() / 4);` to `long startOffset = ((long)startTime * audioFormat.getSampleSizeInBits() * (long)audioFormat.getSampleRate() / 4);` and similarly for `length`.  For some reason changing where the cast occurs seems to have fixed the static problem (I think), though I'm not sure why.  Now, I think I need to adjust the buffer loop because the end of the sample is getting cut off.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the source of the issue, but this may help you figure it out: [RingDroid](https://code.google.com/p/ringdroid/) is an open source Ringtone creator. It has a waveform editor built in. I once downloaded it and used the Waveform editor (and customized it) for a fun project. This may help you get to where you need to go. Enjoy.

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely helpful. It accomplishes trimming a wav file using basically the same approach that I am. I may have solved the major issue in my code, but I'm not sure why.  See my edits in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in my update is that the cast of `startTime` to long effectively rounds down to the nearest second.  The code below works, though I'm still not really sure why my original casting method did not work.

```
public void TrimToSelection(double startTime, double endTime){
    InputStream wavStream = null; // InputStream to stream the wav to trim
    File trimmedSample = null;  // File to contain the trimmed down sample
    File sampleFile = new File(samplePath); // File pointer to the current wav sample

    // If the sample file exists, try to trim it
    if (sampleFile.isFile()){
        trimmedSample = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC), "trimmedSample.wav");
        if (trimmedSample.isFile()) trimmedSample.delete();

        // Trim the sample down and write it to file
        try {
            wavStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(sampleFile));
            // Javazoom WaveFile class is used to write the wav
            WaveFile waveFile = new WaveFile();
            waveFile.OpenForWrite(trimmedSample.getAbsolutePath(), (int)audioFormat.getSampleRate(), (short)audioFormat.getSampleSizeInBits(), (short)audioFormat.getChannels());
            // The number of bytes of wav data to trim off the beginning
            long startOffset = (long)(startTime * audioFormat.getSampleRate()) * audioFormat.getSampleSizeInBits() / 4;
            // The number of bytes to copy
            long length = ((long)(endTime * audioFormat.getSampleRate()) * audioFormat.getSampleSizeInBits() / 4) - startOffset;
            wavStream.skip(44); // Skip the header
            wavStream.skip(startOffset);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int i = 0;
            while (i < length){
                if (length - i >= buffer.length) {
                    wavStream.read(buffer);
                }
                else { // Write the remaining number of bytes
                    buffer = new byte[(int)length - i];
                    wavStream.read(buffer);
                }
                short[] shorts = new short[buffer.length / 2];
                ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer().get(shorts);
                waveFile.WriteData(shorts, shorts.length);
                i += buffer.length;
            }
            waveFile.Close(); // Complete writing the wave file
            wavStream.close(); // Close the input stream
        } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        finally {
            try {if (wavStream != null) wavStream.close();} catch (IOException e){}
        }
    }
}
```